# Rの関数化とfor文

Tags: r

Rの関数化についての質問です。

関数の中身のfor文だけ実行すると破壊的になりうまくいきますが、、関数として実行すると非破壊的になって更新されていないようです。
グローバル変数が原因かと想像しているのですが、<<-を使ってもうまく行かず、という感じです。

```
func <- function(x1,df){
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i,x1+1] <- min(df[i,1:x1]) 
     }
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数の戻り値を指定してみてはどうでしょうか？

```
func <- function(x1,df){
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i,x1+1] <- min(df[i,1:x1]) 
     }
    df #これを追加
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみましたがコンソールに結果が出てくるだけでうまくいきませんね…return()でもだめでした。

Comment: 上記の変更を施した後、df <- func(x1, df) のように、関数の戻り値をdfに再代入するとdfが「破壊的に」変更されたように見えると思います。

Comment: 無事できました。助かりました。